# Discord.py error when printing string in print command

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a `bot` that prints a message to the console whenever someone in the `Discord` server sends a message. This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author + ' sent a message.')
```

However, when I run this code it gives me an error.

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Member' and 'str'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     print(str(message.author) + ' sent a message.')
```

Explanation:
As you are doing `string concatenation` both operands should be of type `str`

Comment: Please don't spam edit tags for points. `[python]` is more than enough. Version specific tags are to be used only when the version is directly relevant to your question. If you continue to do this, you will be flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks for the comment. But my intention is not what you mentioned. I will take this as a suggestion from experienced member of this stackoverflow. Now understood when to add version specific tags, I will follow your suggestion. Thanks again !!

Comment: As long as you understand... no problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print(str(message.author) + ' sent a message.')
```